# Is there a better way to sync data with ViewModel

Tags: ios, mvvm

I build my project with MVVM. ViewModel provides methods to request data from server. All requests need parameters. If view invoke viewModel methods with parameters view would save this parameters. If view invoke viewModel methods without parameters viewModel would save this parameters and when the parameters changed view should sync it to viewModel. What a good way to solve this problem.